# MYSQL subquery or left join?

Tags: mysql, subquery, left-join

I'm making a little invoice application and I'm stuck on a query to get the total open amount of my invoices.

A little explanation:

I've got 2 tables in the database, `invoices` and `payments` which are related on the column `invoice_id`. It's possible to have multiple payments for one invoice.

What I want to get is the total open amount for all the invoices.

This is what I tried but it doesn't work.

The total_paid amount is not correct, its the sum of the last invoice and not of all invoices.

```
SELECT
  COUNT( * ) AS count,
  SUM( invoice_amount_total ) AS total,
  (SELECT
     SUM( amount ) AS total
   FROM `invoice_payments`
   WHERE `invoice_id` = s.id) AS total_paid
FROM sales_invoices AS s
WHERE s.administration_id = 3
    AND (`invoice_amount_total` <> (SELECT
                      SUM( `amount` ) AS sum
                    FROM `invoice_payments`
                    WHERE `invoice_id` = s.id)
      OR (SELECT
        SUM( amount ) AS sum
          FROM `invoice_payments`
          WHERE `invoice_id` = s.id)IS NULL)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: where is sample data and desired output?

Comment: What does "but it doesnt work" mean? Is there an error or just no output / not the desired output?

Comment: I'm sorry, the ouput is not correct. The total_paid amount is not correct, its the sum of the last invoice and not of all invoices.